# Traefik and Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, traefik, bad-gateway

I've faced with a problem in Traeifk:2 and Docker swarm
I want to Implement my reverse proxy with Traefik2 using DockerSwarm

I have 3 machines (in Virtualbox)

- master.ox           # My DockerSwarm Leader
- worker1.ox          # Worker1
- worker2.ox          # Worker2

this is my "/etc/hosts" file

```
192.168.56.101  master.ox traefik.master.ox hello.master.ox
192.168.56.102  worker1
192.168.56.103  worker2
```

I've done this steps

in master.ox (initializing the swarm leader):

```bash
  docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.56.101
  docker network create --driver overlay my-net
```

and in worker1 and worker2 (joining to the swarm):

```bash
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-2jcok5sisa5kohn1nqqwpnasnj3t7hs7vs7c1cellf1eloyja6-16mnbgywkbpc5ssccw5anu0to 192.168.56.101:2377
```

I set label "category=service" for worker1 and worker2 with command

```bash
docker node update --label-add=category=service worker1
docker node update --label-add=category=service worker2
```

this is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
        
networks: 
  my-net:
    external: true

services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginxdemos/hello
    networks: 
      - my-net
    deploy: 
      labels: 
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=my-net"
        - "traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.service=nginx"
        - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`hello.master.ox`)"
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.category==service

  traefik: 
    image: traefik:latest
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
      - 80:80
    command: 
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmmode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.network=my-net"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--api=true"
      - "--ping=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
    volumes: 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks: 
      - my-net
    deploy: 
      mode: global
      labels: 
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=my-net"
        - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"     
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.master.ox`)"
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
```

but it's not worked as I excepted :(
I receive "Bad Gateway" from "hello.master.ox"

Could you help me :)

I expected by visiting "hello.master.ox", i receive nginx result, but I viewed "Bad Gateway" Error

Comment: I found that I should add docker swarm ports to the firewall on the both manager node and client node

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-centos-7

Comment: can you post the log of traefik?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem
I should add docker swarm ports to firewall on the both manager-node and client-nodes

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-centos-7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).